# How to list (for given two directories) the directories with the same names and relative paths under the trees.

Tags: linux, bash, find

For selected two directories list the directories with the same names and relative paths under the trees. Do not nest calls find.

I dont even know how to start it. Should be some loop or only find command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the directories `a` and `b`, here's another way of looking at it:

```
(cd a && find -type d ; cd ../b && find -type d) | sort | uniq -d
```

If you only want the top level directories listed, adding a `grep` to the pipeline would remove all subdirectories:

```
(cd a && find -type d ; cd ../b && find -type d) | sort | uniq -d | grep '^[^/]*/[^/]*$'
```

Slightly easier to read:

```
(cd a && find -type d ; cd ../b && find -type d) \
  | sort \
  | uniq -d \
  | grep '^[^/]*/[^/]*$'
```

Comment: can't check now if that work, anyway i'm very thankful. (Vote Up requires 15 reputation)

Answer (score 0):

Walk the first directory, recording all subdirectories.  The walk the second and report any time a match is found.  This should work:

```
{ find a -type d; find b -type d; } | 
  awk '/^a/ { a[$NF]=$0 } 
       /^b/ {if( $NF in a) print $0,a[$NF]}' FS=/
```

Note that if a the name of a subdirectory is repeated in a then it will only be listed once, and if a repeat appears in b it will be listed for each appearance.  To fix the first issue, you could simply do `a[$NF]=a[$NF]":"$0`.  Fixing the 2nd is left as an exercise for the reader.  (Rather than printing when the match is found, record the event in an array and report in an END block.)

Comment: @twalberg Awk counts fields.  NF is the number of fields in a line and will work just fine when data is from a pipe.